# In this sentence reversal program, why has char been used and not String?

Tags: java

I was doing a few beginner coding challenges and one of the challenge was making a program that reverses a given String. It worked on words, but as soon as I put in words with spaces between them the program only reversed the first word entered.

I googled "reverse words with spaces in it java" and found this:

```
// Java program to reverse a string
// preserving spaces.
public class ReverseStringPreserveSpace {
    // Function to reverse the string
    // and preserve the space position
    static void reverses(String str)
    {
 
        char[] inputArray = str.toCharArray();
        char[] result = new char[inputArray.length];
 
        // Mark spaces in result
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            if (inputArray[i] == ' ') {
                result[i] = ' ';
            }
        }
 
        // Traverse input string from beginning
        // and put characters in result from end
        int j = result.length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
 
            // Ignore spaces in input string
            if (inputArray[i] != ' ') {
 
                // ignore spaces in result.
                if (result[j] == ' ') {
                    j--;
                }
                result[j] = inputArray[i];
                j--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(result));
    }
 
    // driver function
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        reverses("internship at geeks for geeks");
    }
}
```

1. Why were char arrays used instead of String directly?
2. Can I modify my own code to make it reverse a sentence without following the above code?
   My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ReverseString
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the word to be reversed:");
        String input = s.next();

        String reversed = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = input.charAt(i);
            reversed = ch + reversed;
        }
        System.out.println(reversed);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really the kind of question SO is good at answering, but in an effort to point you in the right direction, I would point out that a `String` is immutable—you can't change the characters it contains, you can only make a complete new `String` instance. So, if your program is all about modifying text, it's easier and more efficient to use mutable character strings like `StringBuilder` and `char[]`.

Comment: By the way, the `char` type is legacy. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. Use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead for working with individual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that you found above was a highly over engineered solution to a very simple problem.

1. Sometimes its better to use char arrays when performing operations on strings because it might increase performance. Strings in java are immutable and every time you mutate a String a new String object is created. So char array can be used to increase the performance of the code.
2. Your code is working fine with sentences when I checked it. I don't really know what issue you are facing.

Edit : You should avoid using scanner.next(); method when taking an input string. Because it only read the string up until a space. Therefore your program is not reading the entire string that you entered.
You should instead use scanner.nextLine(); for reading a String value.

For more info on Scanner class : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

This is a pretty good way of Reversing a String. This probably the most efficient way of reversing a String.

```
public String reverseString(String input) {
        char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
        int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1;
        while(i < j) {
            char temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++; j--;
        }
        return new String(arr);
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much , the .nextLine() method worked perfectly.

Comment: I am glad I could help you, if possible can you mark my answer as correct.